# Why can't I copy values from an editable textbox?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, textbox, copy, right-click

I have a GUI where some values are displayed in an [editable textbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f15-998661.html#f15-1002118). For some reason I cannot copy those values with the mouse. I can select the text, but no drop-down menu appears when I right-click on the selected text. I have been looking all over the place. What am I missing?

Comment: It is called context menu and you are right - there is none in MTALAB by default. But you can still use Ctrl+C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that editable text boxes don't bring up a context menu by default when you right click, but there are a few ways around this if you're wanting to copy text to the clipboard:

1. As [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136967/mikhail) mentions in his comment, you can still highlight the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard.
2. As [Itamar mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427873/why-cant-i-copy-values-from-an-edit-field/4428753#4428753), you can create your own context menu for the editable text box using the functions [UICONTEXTMENU](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontextmenu.html) and [UIMENU](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uimenu.html). Here's a sample implementation that uses the function [CLIPBOARD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clipboard.html) to add the editable text string to the clipboard:

   ```
   hFigure = figure;                             %# Create a figure
   hEdit = uicontrol(hFigure,'Style','edit',...  %# Create an editable text box
                     'String','Enter your name here',...
                     'Position',[30 50 130 20]);
   hCMenu = uicontextmenu;                       %# Create a context menu
   uimenu(hCMenu,'Label','Copy',...              %# Create a menu item
          'Callback',@(hObject,eventData) clipboard('copy',get(hEdit,'String')));
   set(hEdit,'UIContextMenu',hCMenu);            %# Add context menu to control
   ```

   Now you can right click on the control to bring up a menu with one option: "Copy". Note that by selecting this menu item it will copy the editable text string to the clipboard without having to highlight the text first.
3. You can set the [`'ButtonDownFcn'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoije) for your editable text box so that a right click on the control will automatically copy the text string to the clipboard without having to highlight the text or select a menu item. First you would have to save this m-file function to the path:

   ```
   function right_click_copy(hObject,eventData)
     hFigure = get(hObject,'Parent');               %# Get the parent object
     while ~strcmp(get(hFigure,'Type'),'figure')    %# Loop until it is a figure
       hFigure = get(hFigure,'Parent');             %# Keep getting the parents
     end
     if strcmp(get(hFigure,'SelectionType'),'alt')  %# Check for a right click
       clipboard('copy',get(hObject,'String'));     %# Copy the object string to
                                                    %#   the clipboard
     end
   end
   ```

   This function uses the [`'SelectionType'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#SelectionType) of the parent figure to check which mouse button was pressed and the [CLIPBOARD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clipboard.html) function to copy the object string to the clipboard. Now you can create your editable text control as follows:

   ```
   hFigure = figure;                             %# Create a figure
   hEdit = uicontrol(hFigure,'Style','edit',...  %# Create an editable text box
                     'String','Enter your name here',...
                     'Position',[30 50 130 20],...
                     'ButtonDownFcn',@right_click_copy);
   ```

   This is the quickest and easiest option of the three, since it involves only a single mouse click to copy the editable text string to the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement the context menu yourself, if you need one, by using `uicontextmenu` uicontrol, and adding items to it using `uimenu`. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontextmenu.html

Answer (score -1):

Did you just want to make the editable textbox 'Enable'?

> set(handles.editbox1,'Enable','on');

(assuming that you have the 'handle' to that GUI object.)

This should make the edit box editable.